# Using callbacks in ReactJS with Hooks returns "not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing a website using ReactJS and i am using Material UI components. Since Material UI is using a lot of Hooks, at least for this project i have used the same approach so far. However, when setting up the database, i want to pass a callback from one component to another. The class traditional way would be to bind a function and just pass it. However, with hooks i have no "this" to bind to. I tried simply passing it.

```
 <Route path="/signUp/" render={ (receiveData) => <SignUpPage dataCallback={receiveData} /> } />
```

^this is what i do using the router-react-dom (afaik this is the official solution to pass props to a routed component).However, when the receiveData function "reaches" the other component and i try to access it via props.dataCallback(), i get an error that the result is not a function.

So far i have looked into the docs and the first "solution" i have found is to use useEffect. However, useEffect is called whenever the DOM is re-rendered and i only need it called when a Button is clicked. I have looked into other hooks like useContext but with no success.

Comment: dataCallback is component rendering to route with function parameters so you can't call props.dataCallback directly, try to console log render attribute.

Comment: Where do you get `receiveData` from? I don't think it has anything to do with Hooks. Try smth like `render={ (props) => <SignUpPage dataCallback={receiveData} {...props} /> }`

Comment: put more code into your question, there is something with how you declare that `receiveData`

Comment: @Clarity this seems to have been it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

User Clarity has provided the answer that fixed my problem, but instead of

```
render={ (props) => <SignUpPage dataCallback={receiveData} {...props} /> }
```

i just did

```
render={ (props) => <SignUpPage dataCallback={receiveData} /> } />
```

I am not entirely sure why this worked, but nonetheless i am happy. Will look into docs but i suspect "props" is treated as an object and putting my function there was making it seem like i wanted it to be an object.

Comment: This worked because when you render a Route, it passes its own props to your component, like `match`, `location`, etc. and you were passing those props as `dataCallback`.